# How do i write this if statement in java

Tags: java

i know this is easy but i am new to java. We are learning if, else and the while loop in class. I  i don't know how to write the "if" part in this problem. So i don't if i need to declare a new string name excellent or something like that.

```
//****************************************************************************************
//
// Computes the amount of raise and the new 
// salary for an employee. The current salary
//  and a performance rating (A string: Excellent", "Good" or "Poor") are input.
//****************************************************************************************

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Salary1
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    double currentSalary; //employee's current salary
    double raise;         // amount of the raise
    double newSalary;     // new salary of the employee
    String rating;        // performance rating



    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print ("Enter the current salary: ");
    currentSalary = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print ("Enter the Performance rating (Excellent, Good, or Poor): ");
    rating = scan.next();

    // Compute the the raise using if....


    newSalary = (currentSalary + raise);

    //print the results 
    NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Current Salary:          " + money.format(currentSalary));
    System.out.println("Amount of your raise:    " + money.format(raise));
    System.out.println("Your new salary:         " + money.format(newSalary));
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: Before you go any further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Where is your problem? `if(condition){ code here } else { another code }`

Comment: Unrelated, but raise hasn't been initialised. And is there only one case where the employee would receive a raise?

Comment: well, the first step is, don't skip class :)

Comment: @RafaEl is absolutely right. To learn about [if-then and if-then-else statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score -1):

The pseudo-code for `if` statements looks like this:

```
if(/*boolean value*/) {
    // code to execute when the part in parenthesis is true
} else {
    // code to execute when the part in parenthesis is false
}
```

In the above pseudo-code snippet, `/*boolean value*/` can be replaced by anything that can be evaluated to `true` or `false`.  This includes:

- Boolean variables
- Integers data types (where 0 is false and non-zero is true)
- Methods that return Boolean or Integer data types
- Comparison expression (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`)
- Any combination of the above, combined using the Boolean operators (`||`, `&&`)

And as a side note, you can obtain the inverse boolean value of any of these using an `!`.

It is also worth mentioning that the `else` part of the statement is completely optional.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) will help get you started on comparing strings in Java (with a method that will return a boolean value.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?  The question is about writing `if` statements in Java.  Did I miss something?